# Unable to get intellij option instead just getting maven gradle option only

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

This is my screenshot where you can find that.

[image]

Comment: If it has been there then it already has been checked, so kindly help something useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the project using `New Project` option:

[image]

and add all the needed dependencies/configurations manually as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.3/javafx.html .

When creating a project with JavaFX project wizard and selecting Maven/Gradle, the IDE will configure everything automatically. E.g. add JavaFX plugin to the pom.xml/build.gradle, download all the needed dependencies, etc... so that you can launch the project out of the box.